# Can't use string as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use

Tags: perl, dictionary, hash, hashmap

First off, I know this is a fairly common issue but I have looked around and can't quite seem to pinpoint why its happening to me!

I have some data I am reading from a `JSON` file, basically all it is are a set of string that represent IDs.

I import it like so:

```
 my $idFile='IDS.json';
 my $idJSON;



 {
         local $/;
         open my $fh, '<', $idFile or die $!;
         $idJSON = <$fh>;
         close $fh;
 }

 my $id_array = decode_json $idJSON;
```

This is what `$id_array` looks like now:

```
$VAR1 = [
          '3233',
          '2758',
          '2797'
        ];
```

I then save them with a `MISC` tag in the form of a hash map, but this is where my `"Can't use string ("3233") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use "` error is being thrown:

`my @decodedIDS = map { $_ ->{MISC}} @{$id_array};`

Anyone have suggestions as to what is causing this error? Any help is greatly appreciated, as always.

Comment: I'm unclear what you're trying to do...can you please explain what you want `@decodedIDS` to contain?

Comment: "I then save them with a MISC tag in the form of a hash map" ... then maybe you meant to say `@decodedIDS = map { MISC => $_ } @{$id_array}`?

Comment: That's not a hash, @mob. `my %decodedIDS = map { $_ => 1 } @$id_array;` would create a hash keyed by id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand what you're trying to do but below is the reason of the error.

```
map { $_->{MISC} } @{$id_array}
```

means take each element from given dereferenced arrayref and access the `MISC` key of that element (it is expecting the element to be a hashref). In your case the element is literal string (3233 for example). So it kinda looks like this:

```
3233->{MISC}
```

Therefore you get below error:

> "Can't use string ("3233") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use

Comment: Ahh realized my mistake. Earlier this script was expecting a JSOn input of id:'MISC'. But now the JSON is simply containing the id. Pretty easy fix, since I have no use for the map anymore and simply pass each id from my id_array into my main code.